# Kotlin readline Does not work well when copying and pasting

Tags: java, kotlin

When receiving vertices and trunk lines from the bfs code below, it works well when typing on the keyboard, but not when copying and pasting.

How can we solve this?

(I'm sorry that the title and content of the question are strange. It's because I used a translator.)

```kotlin
import java.util.*
import kotlin.collections.ArrayDeque

fun bfs(graph: MutableList<MutableList<Int>>, v: Int, visited: MutableList<Boolean>) {
    val q = ArrayDeque<Int>()

    q.addLast(v)

    visited[v] = true

    while (q.isNotEmpty()) {
        val popped = q.removeFirst()

        print("$popped ")

        for (x in graph[popped].sorted()) {
            if (visited[x].not()) {
                visited[x] = true
                q.addLast(x)
            }
        }
    }
}

fun main() {
    val v: Int
    val graph: MutableList<MutableList<Int>>

    with(Scanner(System.`in`)) {
        v = nextInt()

        // 비어있는 2중 리스트 생성
        graph=(0..v).map{
            mutableListOf<Int>()
        }.toMutableList()

        // 각 버텍스(정점)에 연결된 엣지(간선) 받기
        for(i in 1..v){
            readLine()?.split(" ")?.map {
                it.toIntOrNull()?.let { element ->
                    graph[i].add(element)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // 방문 기록 불 리스트 생성. (모두 방문안함=false 로)
    val visited = (1..9).map { false }.toMutableList() // 타입 보는 방법 shift+control

    // 1번 정점부터 방문.
    bfs(graph, 1, visited)
}
```

```kotlin
// Enter or paste the line below
8
2 3 8
1 7
1 4 5
3 5
3 4
7
2 6 8
1 7
// output (Works only if entered directly by typing)
1 2 3 8 7 4 5 6
```

Comment: There's a lot of unnecessary code there (as well as comments that most of us won't understand!).  Could you edit it down to a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem here is that you're trying to use `System.in` in two different ways, and they're interfering with each other:

- The `Scanner` reads `System.in` explicitly.
- But `readLine()` also reads `System.in`.

The `Scanner` may well pre-read some text, which is not then available to `readLine()`.

The solution is to use only one or the other.  (Since your input seems to be line-based, it's probably better to use only `readLine()`.  Or a better alternative might be one of Kotlin's higher-level input functions, such as [`forEachLine()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-reader/for-each-line.html) or [`readLines()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-reader/read-lines.html), though you'd need to call [`reader()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-input-stream/reader.html) on `System.in` to convert the bytes into characters.  You could then use a Scanner on each line — or, probably better, just [split()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/split.html) it.)

Answer (score 0):

It works if you modify it as below.

```kotlin
        v = readLine()!!.toInt()//nextInt()
```